# WebApp.Start<Startup> with WebSocket-scheme ws://

Tags: web-services, websocket, owin

I'm trying to get a very basic echo WebSocket-server running self-hosted with Owin. But how do I do that? When specifying the url i WebApp.Start as for instance "ws://localhost:1337" I get a message saying "ws" is not supported, only "http(s)". Is it not possible to use Owin.Hosting to host WebSocket on ws(s)?

I'm also using [Owin.WebSocket](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.WebSocket/) to integrate WebSockets into Owin.

Comment: you have to install web sockets on your machine.

BTW use Signal

Answer (score 0):

specify `http://` on the server. You only need to use `ws://` on the client.